# inkscape not working from command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, pdf, batch, conversion

I was looking at the answer to the [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/what-are-good-ways-to-convert-eps-to-pdf) (converting EPS to PDF) where they suggested using Inkscape to convert EPS to PDF images. I need the exact same thing. Using the GUI, it works like a charm.

Since I have about 200 images to convert, is there a way to automate this process? Or at least run it via command line so that I can do this process faster? Even doing it one at a time from command prompt is fine because doing this from GUI is becoming a pain.

I'm learning Batch scripting so with any given answer can you elaborate to how the proccess works

I have read the [page](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine.html) on running Inkscape on the command prompt but I'm getting the error that 'inkscape' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132676/inkscape-from-command-prompt/132678?noredirect=1#132676) over at [the TeX StackExchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and was asked to run the following batch script.

```
@echo off

for /r %%i in (*.eps) do "c:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --export-pdf=%%i.pdf %%i
```

When I navigate to using cmd to the directory I get the error

> Inkscape has received additional data from the script executed.  The script did not return an error, but this may indicate the results will not be as expected.

But Inkscape just opened and nothing happened after that. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Run the script with `>> output.txt` at the end of `for /r %%i in (*.eps) do "c:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --export-pdf=%%i.pdf %%i` and it will output the errors to a text file

Comment: Also `for /r %%i in (*.eps) do echo "c:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --export-pdf=%%i.pdf %%i >> output.txt` will output each line that the batch file tries to run into a text file so you can see each line and debug from there

Answer (score 7):

- Don't use `inkscape.exe`. Use the `inkscape.com` wrapper. This will allow you to see output and error messages from the Windows command line. See [this FAQ entry](https://inkscape.org/en/learn/faq/#how-to-use-inkscape-from-the-command-line)
- Try explicitly using the `-f` option to see if that makes a difference, ie. change:

  ```
  --export-pdf=%%i.pdf %%i
  ```

  to

  ```
  -f "%%i" --export-pdf="%%i.pdf"
  ```
- Test a single file with backslashes in the path to make sure Inkscape is okay with it. If not, you might need to convert to forward slashes.

Comment: Thank you... but oh wow... Is there a single step in the process of importing `svg` into `pdf` files that is not painful?

Answer (score 1):

With the `/r` option of `for`, you are getting a recursive list of all the .eps files in that directory and subdirector(y/ies), with the value of `%%i` = `c:\some\path\probably with\spaces\someEPSfile.eps`.

Inkscape is probably choking on those unexpected spaces in the filename. It can probably be fixed like this:

```
for /r %%i in (*.eps) do "c:\Program Files(x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe"
--export-pdf="%%i.pdf" "%%i"
```

If that doesn't work, then I would try removing the recursive flag (maybe Inkscape doesn't like slashes in it's filenames?):

```
for %%i in (*.eps) do "c:\Program Files(x86)\Inkscape\inkscape.exe"
--export-pdf="%%i.pdf" "%%i"
```